# Passing the Id to get the element when the Id is dynamic in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have this sample app in which small thumbnails are shown on screen fetched from a database.

Requirement: When a thumbnail is clicked, it should open in a modal as a large image, and each image should have its own download button when popped-up.

Issue - PHP is running fine. I can open image when clicked, but I don't have any clear thoughts on how to implement a download button for each image.

Note - I use prepared statements always, but this is just a sample, so I didn't use anything special.

Here is my code:

```
<?php   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>

    <img id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" src="<?php echo $row['img_name'] ?>" alt="">

<?php } ?>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript code

```
// Get the modal
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".imgwrap > img");

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
for(i=0; i<images.length; i++){
  let img = images[i];

  // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the image on the modal you have to add event listeners to each of the thumbnails. That way you can display them on the modal or do whatever you want, when an it is clicked. I've created a working demo here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jyotishmoy/pen/XWZZrvM). Please check it out.

HTML

```
<div class="images-wrapper">
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
    
    <img class="gallery-img" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" src="<?php echo $row['img_name'] ?>" alt="">

    <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="close-modal" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
//select all thumbnails on the page generated by php
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".images-wrapper > img")

//loop over all the images and bind an eventlistener on click to each images 
for(i=0; i<images.length; i++){
  let img = images[i]
  img.addEventListener('click', showModal, false)
}

let modal = document.querySelector("#myModal")

function showModal(){
  
  //display mdodal
  modal.style.display = 'block'
  
  //select modal body element
  let modalBody = document.querySelector("#modal-body")
  
  //clear previously displayed image
  modalBody.innerHTML = ""
  
  //create an image element 
  let modalImg = document.createElement('img')
  modalImg.src = this.getAttribute('src')
  
  //create download btn
  let downloadBtn = document.createElement('a')
  // Create the text node
  let link = document.createTextNode("Download Image");
  downloadBtn.appendChild(link); 
  downloadBtn.href = this.getAttribute('src')
  downloadBtn.download = 'download'
  
  // add download btn 
  modalBody.prepend(downloadBtn)
  
  // add image element to modal body
  modalBody.appendChild(modalImg);
  
}

let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-modal")
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal, false)

//close modal
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you code is not getting the data(images) dynamically from database through php, but still I tried to study your code and modified mine and now update my code here. 
No the issue is How to implement a download button for each image when poped-up. Basically download button should come in the modal.

Comment: @Sameer I've updated my code to include the download button on the modal. Also I've placed your PHP code where it belongs to generate dynamic images the way you mentioned.

Comment: Thankyou so much once again, so from what I understood you are creating the 'img' tag and 'a' tag from javascript, also how can I place the Image first then download button in html structure.